# Separating address and phone number into two cells in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, I have many cells that have an address and a phone number in this format

```
78 North Oak Street Philadelphia PA 17545 610-634-2452
```

And I want to remove the phone number from this cell and place it into a new cell in another column. Is there anyway I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AAA-PPP-NNNN
```

A = Area Code
P = Local Prefix
N = Subscriber Number

Given the following conditions:

- Phone number is always in the above format.
- Phone number is always at the end.
- Phone number is always separated from Address by exactly one space.
- There are no trailing spaces or other characters after the phone number.

These formulas should work for you. (Assumes data is in A2.)

Address:

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-13)
```

Phone number:

```
=RIGHT(A2,12)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. If I wanted to use this formula for many rows, how would I do about doing this without manually entering the updated formula for each row?

Comment: Copy & Paste the cell (not the formula text). Excel should automatically adjust the formula accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the format is always the same you could do:

Phone `=RIGHT(A1,12)`

Address `=MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-12)`

For the address, use `LEN(A1)-13` if you don't want the additional space, as shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Will the phone number always be available in the same format and at the end with exact same length? If so, you can extract just portion and put it on to a separate column as phone number. Similarly, ignore just the phone number and save the string in a separate column for address. You can make use of ["mid" function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/mid-midb-functions-HP010342690.aspx) to achieve the same.

Usage is as below:

> =MID(A1, LEN(TRIM(A1))-12, 12)

The above will extract the phone number alone.